# Unequal (graphical) Bar Sizes in a PowerPoint 100% Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: powerpoint

I am working with a 100% stacked bar chart in PowerPoint where each bar is supposed to represent a total percentage divided among various categories. However, I've noticed that one of the bars in the chart is (graphically) noticeably larger than the others, i.e. it is too wide. (See picture attached). [One of the bars is too wide and it sticks out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auz0P.png)

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or could anyone suggest why this might be happening and how to resolve it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I have checked on multiple PCs, while screen-presenting etc.; I also tried to play around with the size of all bars, used different colors, etc.

Comment: It'd be easier to diagnose this if we could look at an actual slide rather than just an image. But my first guess would be that the series has been formatted to apply an outline to the bars (of the same color as the bar itself).

Comment: Hey Steve, thank you so much – it was exactly as you said (I don't understand why it was like this) and it's fixed now.

Comment: Glad it helped. As to why ... I doubt there's anyone in the room who hasn't accidentally clicked on something/moved something by mistake w/o realizing it. Just yesterday my wife panicked when a whole folder of files she'd worked on for days just ... poof! ... disappeared. Because, as it turns out, she'd accidentally dragdropped the folder onto the adjacent folder. Ooopsie!  Did I make fun of her?  Not a chance.  Done the same thing myself far too often.

Comment: Well you are right, I guess it happens to the best of us! However, now I'll know what to check when this occurs next time. Cheers!